# TDD approach when using a data access layer and an application layer

Tags: python, database, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm new to TDD. I want some tips on how to unit tests an application formed by a data layer that implements actual database access statements, and an application layer whose job is limited to calling the data layer methods. For example :

In my data layer class, called CassandraDataLayer, I have a retrieveMessage method :

```
class CassandraDataLayer:

    def retrieveMessage(self,message_id):
        #database access statements to retrieve the message
        #returns a Message class instance
```

On the other hand, in my application layer class, called ApplicationLayer, I have the following retrieveMessage method :

```
class ApplicationLayer:

    def retrieveMessage(self,message_id):
        return self.dataLayer.retrieveMessage(message_id)
```

Do I have to do unit tests for both of the two methods ?

To test my CassandraDataLayer retrieveMessage method, I've proceeded as the following :

1. I instantiate a test database.
2. I manually insert a message into it
3. Then, I call the retrieveMessage to attempt to retrieve the message
4. Finally, assert that the inserted message and the retrieved one are equal.

But, then, how can I test the application layer class retrieveMessage method ? Do I have to use the same logic again ? Isn't it redudant ?

Comment: It seems that the reason your tests seem redundant is that your code is redundant. This may be due to how limited the example is, but all your application layer code does is return what the data layer code returns to it. As such, all you would be testing is whether your compiler/interpreter processes return statements correctly. Maybe you need a more involved example?  EDIT: sorry, I missed the Python tag. Interpreter is the right word there.

Comment: Actually, it's the first iteration of my application. For now, I want it to return the results on the console. So, It's not rare to have this kind of redundancy between my data layer and my application layer, there is not any printing or linking logic yet. So it's what I actually have in my application, and I'm just confused by such cases. Do I have to drop unit tests for the application layer when it is so redundant ?

Comment: That is totally acceptable. My point is that since your application is so new, and there is so little differentiation between data and app layers, it should be obvious that the tests would be redundant. As you add code that differentiates between the two, the two tests will surely be less redundant.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer.

Comment: Perhaps you should write your answer as an "anwser" to the question instead of a comment, so I can make my issue resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, I'm moving my two comments to this answer for clarity's sake.

The reason that your tests seem redundant is that at the moment, your code is rather redundant. Because the application layer's behavior is only to return what is returned to it via the data layer, the only thing your second test is confirming right now is whether or not the interpreter handles return calls properly (which ideally, is an invariant of your code :).

As you continue to add functionality to the application layer, TDD mandates that you also modify this test or add others to test that functionality, and so your test for data layer and application layer will look less redundant as the two UUT's go the same.